# How do I verify that my 6 GB/s SATA ports are working under Linux?

Tags: linux, sata

How do I verify that my 6 GB/s SATA ports are working under Linux?

Linux detects the ports, and I can use them for disks but I would like to figure out if they are using a 6 GB/s controller/driver instead of the slower, more common speed.

Comment: Do you have any SSD capable of saturating 3Gb/s SATA? The only one so far is Crucial RealSSD C300.

Comment: Yes. We have two of the Curcial RealSSD C300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

> grep -i sata /var/log/messages | less

The resulting output should contain a number of lines that look like "ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)" This would be a good place to start!

Comment: Cool! I see SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)

Comment: Then you, sir, are probably doing just fine! Good luck with it!